# async await in objective-c Firebase API

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to change following obj-c Firebase API standard code:

```
void (^block)(FIRDataSnapshot *);
block = ^void(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    FIRDatabaseQuery *query;

    [query observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
                  withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    }];
};

FIRDatabaseQuery *query;

[query observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:block];
```

and use better alternative similar to `Promise` used in Firebase Functions node.js:

```
const promise1 = query.once('value');
const promise2 = query.once('value');
await Promise.all( [promise1, promise2] );
```

any good way of making `observe` call synchronous (waiting for return) may enable the use of native [NSOperation Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html)

```
NSOperation *promise1;
NSOperation *promise2;
NSOperation *promise_all;

[promise2    addDependency:promise1];
[promise_all addDependency:promise2];

NSOperationQueue *Q;
[Q addOperation:promise_all];
```